# Access violation при обращении к элементам массива

Tags: delphi

создал динамический массив TBitmap'ов, после чего сделал SetLength и заполнил, то бишь циклически создал и прогрузил картинками.

```
procedure TFormGame.WaveStart;
var counter:integer;
begin
  if WaveNumber<11 then begin
    SetLength(PanzerFaust,EnemyCounter);
    for counter:=  0 to EnemyCounter do begin
      PanzerFaust[Counter]:=TBitmap.Create;
      PanzerFaust[Counter].LoadFromFile('PanzerToRight.bmp');
    end;
    TimerSpawn.Enabled:=True;
    EC1:=1;
  end
  else ShowMessage('Фашистская Германия подписала акт о безоговорочной капитуляции');
end;
```

на что дельфи выдал мне эту ошибку в первый раз. Затем, как видите, активируется таймер, запускающий следующую процедуру:

```
procedure TFormGame.TimerSpawnTimer(Sender: TObject);
var counter:integer;
begin
  TimerMove.Enabled:=true;
  if EC1<=EnemyCounter then begin
    ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(50,50,PanzerFaust[EC1]);
    EC1:=EC1+1;
  end;
end;
```

При каждом тике таймера он выдает мне ту же ошибку.
Мой вопрос заключается в следующем: как это исправить?
спасибо заранее

Answer (score 2):

Последний индекс массива длиной `EnemyCounter` равен `EnemyCounter  - 1`.

```
for counter := 0 to EnemyCounter - 1 do begin

EC1 := 0;

if EC1 < EnemyCounter then begin
```

Да, и включите "Range Checking" в опциях компилятора.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в вашем коде начинается вот здесь:

```
SetLength(PanzerFaust, EnemyCounter); // Создаете массив EnemyCounter элементов
for counter := 0 to EnemyCounter do begin // Проходите циклом по EnemyCounter + 1 элементам
```

и продолжается вот здесь:

```
// EC1 не установлен в начале прохода?

if EC1 <= EnemyCounter then begin // перебираете до EnemyCounter + 1 элемента
  ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(50,50,PanzerFaust[EC1]);
  EC1:=EC1+1;
end;
```

Итого: Вы путаете количество элементов в массиве. При динамическом задании размера, оно всегда `0 .. Count - 1`. И перебирать их, соответственно надо от `0` до `Count - 1`