# Delphi выдает access violation error

Tags: delphi

Во время процедуры `TimerMoveTimer` выдает мне ошибку (имеется ввиду попапы с аккесс вайолэйшн).

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
ClassPanzer=class(TObject)
x,y,hp:integer;
Bmp:TBitmap;
end;

  TFormGame = class(TForm)
    ImageGround: TImage;
    TimerSpawn: TTimer;
    TimerMove: TTimer;
    TimerShoot: TTimer;
    ButtonSender: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure TimerSpawnTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TimerMoveTimer(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  FormGame: TFormGame;
  PanzerFaust:array of ClassPanzer;
  PanzerToRight,PanzerToUp,PanzerToLeft,PanzerToDown,BitMapGround,BitMapRoad,BitMapBaseSovjet,BitMapBaseNazi:TBitmap;
  WaveCount,Gold,EnemyCounter:integer;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormGame.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
var Counter1:integer;
begin
//
PanzerToRight.Free;
PanzerToUp.Free;
PanzerToLeft.Free;
PanzerToDown.Free;
BitMapGround.Free;
BitMapRoad.Free;
BitMapBaseSovjet.Free;
BitMapBaseNazi.Free;
//
for Counter1:=1 to Length(PanzerFaust) do PanzerFaust[Counter1].Free;
//
end;

procedure TFormGame.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var counter1,counter2, counter3 :integer;
begin
// procedure begin
EnemyCounter:=1;
counter3:=1;
PanzerToRight:=TBitmap.Create;
PanzerToRight.LoadFromFile('PanzerToRight.bmp');
//
PanzerToUp:=TBitmap.Create;
PanzerToUp.LoadFromFile('PanzerToUp.bmp');
//
PanzerToLeft:=TBitmap.Create;
PanzerToLeft.LoadFromFile('PanzerToLeft.bmp');
//
PanzerToDown:=TBitmap.Create;
PanzerToDown.LoadFromFile('PanzerToDown.bmp');
//
BitMapGround:=TBitmap.Create;
BitMapGround.LoadFromFile('Ground.bmp');
//
BitMapRoad:=TBitmap.Create;
BitMapRoad.LoadFromFile('Road.bmp');
//
BitMapBaseSovjet:=TBitmap.Create;
BitMapBaseSovjet.LoadFromFile('SovjetBase.bmp');
//
BitmapBaseNazi:=TBitmap.Create;
BitMapBaseNazi.LoadFromFile('NaziBase.bmp');
for   counter1:=1 to 20 do for counter2:= 1 to 20 do ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(counter2*50-50,counter1*50-50,BitMapGround);
//
for   counter1:=1 to 10 do for counter2:= 1 to 20 do ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(Counter2*50-50,counter1*100-50,BitMapRoad);
//
counter3:=100;
for counter1:=1 to 5 do begin
ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(950,counter3,BitMapRoad);
counter3:=counter3+200;
end;
//
counter3:=200;
for counter1:=1 to 4 do begin
ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(0,counter3,BitMapRoad);
counter3:=counter3+200;
end;
//
ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(0,050,BitMapBaseNazi);
ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(0,950,BitMapBaseSovjet);
//
WaveCount:=1;
ButtonSender.Click;
TimerSpawn.Enabled:=true;
//procedure end
end;
//
procedure TFormGame.TimerMoveTimer(Sender: TObject);
var counter:integer;
begin
for counter:= 0 to WaveCount*50 div 4 do begin
if ((PanzerFaust[Counter].y=50) or (PanzerFaust[Counter].y=250) or (PanzerFaust[Counter].y=450)  or (PanzerFaust[Counter].y=650) or (PanzerFaust[Counter].y=850)) and (Panzerfaust[Counter].x<950) and (PanzerFaust[Counter].x>50) then begin;
PanzerFaust[Counter].Bmp:=PanzerToRight;
ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(PanzerFaust[Counter].x,PanzerFaust[Counter].y,BitMapRoad);
Panzerfaust[Counter].x:=PanzerFaust[Counter].x+2;
ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(PanzerFaust[Counter].x,PanzerFaust[Counter].y,PanzerToRight);
end;
end;
end;

procedure TFormGame.TimerSpawnTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
if EnemyCounter<=WaveCount*50 div 4 then begin
SetLength(Panzerfaust,EnemyCounter);
PanzerFaust[EnemyCounter].x:=60;
PanzerFaust[EnemyCounter].y:=50;
PanzerFaust[EnemyCounter].hp:=100;
PanzerFaust[EnemyCounter].bmp:=PanzerToRight;
ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(PanzerFaust[EnemyCounter].x,PanzerFaust[EnemyCounter].y,PanzerFaust[EnemyCounter].bmp);
EnemyCounter:=EnemyCounter+1;
TimerMove.Enabled:=true;
end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: в с какой то принципиальной целью уже в который раз вставляете неотформатированный код? И вам уже вроде советовали поставить брейк на нужном методе, и пошагово ловить ошибку.

Comment: Убедитесь в очередной раз, что `WaveCount*50 div 4` не выведет вас за пределы массива. И установить `RangeCheck`, как говорилось, в настройках компиляции.

Comment: Если честно, при любой попытке дебага глаза разбегаюься... Скажу честно, информатику учу в школе, ъотя вряд ли ей буду пользоваться... Поэтому для меня все термины принципиально новы

Comment: А чего там глаза разбегаются? Просто находясь в конкретной точке определите в нужных вам переменных лежат нужные вам данные? Если это объекты Вам будет достаточно увидеть что они НЕ `nil` или же `nil` если вы в этом уверены!

Comment: 1. в массиве (кроме строк, в некоторых случаях) счисление идет не с 1 а с 0.

2.  PanzerFaust:array of ClassPanzer; - где у тебя идет инициализация элементов массива?

Comment: А разве тут вы примерно не про то же самое спрашивали? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/640443

Comment: Нет, там была другая ошибка...

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка access violation практически всегда является следствием обращения к не инициализированной области памяти.

В методе TimerMoveTimer потенциально опасным с этой точки зрения местом является массив PanzerFaust и его элементы.

И в приведенном коде нигде нет инициализации элементов массива.

Вообще ошибка должна была появиться еще в методе TimerSpawnTimer на строке PanzerFaust[EnemyCounter].x:=60; т.к. память под объект не была выделена.